# My columns keep smashing into each other

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I'm trying to have two jumbotrons indicating two portals into my site. On a medium-large screen they appear side by side with spacing in between. On a tablet or mobile device I would like the jumbotrons to be stacked. The docs on the bootstrap 3 make this automatically happen when I shrink the page, however this isn't happening to me. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong, I'm really new to bootstrap. Right now when it becomes a medium sized screen the white space disappears and they get squeezed side by side.

My html looks like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container special">
            <div class="clearfix visible-sx"></div>
            <div class="jumbotron text-center col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
                <h1>Become a Screener</h1>
                <p>Yahh a screener.</p>
                <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'screener_info' %}">More Info</a>
            </div>

            <div class="jumbotron text-center col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
                <h1>Have your books screened</h1>
                <p>yah an author.</p>
                <a class="btn btn-success" href="{% url 'author_info' %}" role="button">More Info</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your code to this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container special">
            <div class="clearfix visible-sx"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-offset-1">
                <div class="jumbotron text-center">
                    <h1>Become a Screener</h1>
                    <p>Yahh a screener.</p>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'screener_info' %}">More Info</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-offset-1">
                <div class="jumbotron text-center">
                    <h1>Have your books screened</h1>
                    <p>yah an author.</p>
                    <a class="btn btn-success" href="{% url 'author_info' %}" role="button">More Info</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Simply create a div around jumbotrons with md-5 and offset class.

Comment: That fixed the spacing so the spacing stays, however, it doesn't stack when it gets to sm, or sx size

Comment: you need to use col-sm-5 instead of col-md-5 for small screens

Comment: To funny I discovered that exactly when you posted :D OK, now the problem is that the sized of the jombotrons no longer when one has a longer text then the other :(

Comment: add media queries and change font-size(make it smaller) when jumbotron breaks